# why is my mongodb async save failing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

Here's the code; any pointers where am I going wrong?
Is it the way I am using promises?  i was expecting that the call to insert() will check whether valid db conn exists, everytime before doing a save...

no errors, but no entry in the db.
also, the console log 'connecting' is displayed once, as expected - the second insert reuses the connection (or i expect it to)...

```
// mongoApi.js

var assert = require('assert');
var promise = require('bluebird');
var mongoClient = promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb').MongoClient);
var log = require('./logger.js');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost/yangDB';
var dbconn = false;

var getDb = function () {
    if (!this.dbconn) {
        console.log('connecting...')
        this.dbconn = mongoClient.connectAsync(url);
    }
    return this.dbconn;
};

var insert = function (doc) {
    getDb().then(function (db) {
        db.collection('yangTemplates').save(doc);
    });
};

insert( { "first insert" : new Date() } );
insert({ "second insert" : new Date() } );

// eventually: module.exports.insert = insert;
// main.js: var mapi = require('./mongoApi.js'); mapi.insert({a:true});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `mongoClient.connectAsync(url);` is an async call... and when you try and return `this.dbconn` the async call hasn't actually finished.

Comment: @tymeJV: He returns a promise

Comment: How do you check whether there is an entry in the db?

Comment: Notice that you should `return` your promises from `insert` and the `then()` callback. Of course, Bluebird should report unhandled rejections anyway. Try logging after the `save()` call. Is that shown in your logs?